# Place pagination at top of DT Datatable in R?

Tags: r, datatable, dt

I'm working with a very long datatable and would like to place the pagination (1, 2, 3, ...15, next) at the top rather than the bottom of the table.

I know the DOM elements can be included/excluded as an option, but I don't see how to actually move them around.

How can a simple table like this move the pagination to the top?

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dom options.  See https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom for details on the various options available.  To place pagination at top use:

```
datatable(iris, options = list(dom = '<"top" p>'))
```

[image]

If you also need other elements such as information and search, add them in the same way, e.g.

```
datatable(iris, options = list(dom = '<"top" pif>'))
```

[image]

Comment: For pagination both at top and bottom: datatable(iris, options = list(dom = '<"top"lpf<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>' ))

Answer (score 0):

The "dom" argument passed as a list in the options argument to datatable seems to arrange things.

```
datatable(head(iris, 30), options = list(dom = '<lfp<t>i>'))
```

[image]
The t is for the table, p for pagination, between `<` and `<` at the top, between `>` and `>` at the bottom.

```
datatable(head(iris, 30))
```

[image]

Comment: this seems only incrementally different to my earlier answer

Comment: You must've posted while I was looking for the answer.  Looks like we got to the same place, but you beat me by a few minutes, and with better formatting.